# ACF select output choice on front

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Im trying to get a select field working with two subfields, one being a textfield with a pre-defined value and the second a post object (product) where I want to extract the url and the thumb.

Spent quite some time trying different options, specifically how to retrieve the product, but no luck.

To simplify the process I started looking into something like this, even though it doesnt help me correctly with retrieving the product info I want, but this doesn't work either.

```
$choice = get_sub_field('block_one_ select_type');
if ($choice == 'checkbox') {
// do something
} elseif ($choice == 'product') {
$product = get_field('pdp_product_one');
// do something
}
```

I also tried this, no output:

```
 if(have_rows('pdp_banner', 'options')){
 while(have_rows('pdp_banner', 'options')){
 the_row();
 $test = get_sub_field('block_one_select_type'); 
 }
 }

 echo $test;
```

This is the ACF setup:

```
         array(
            'key' => 'field_5f7efd01f2427',
            'label' => 'PDP banner',
            'name' => 'pdp_banner',
            'type' => 'group',
            'instructions' => '',
            'required' => 0,
            'conditional_logic' => 0,
            'wrapper' => array(
                'width' => '',
                'class' => '',
                'id' => '',
            ),
            'collapsed' => '',
            'min' => 0,
            'max' => 0,
            'layout' => 'group',
            'button_label' => 'banner block',
            'sub_fields' => array( 
                                    array(
                    'key' => 'field_5f7efd35f2428',
                    'label' => 'Block one select type',
                    'name' => 'block_one_select_type',
                    'type' => 'select',
                    'instructions' => '',
                    'required' => 0,
                    'conditional_logic' => 0,
                    'wrapper' => array(
                        'width' => '',
                        'class' => '',
                        'id' => '',
                    ),
                    'choices' => array(
                        'checkbox' => 'Checkbox',
                        'product' => 'Product',
                    ),
                    'default_value' => array(
                    ),
                    'allow_null' => 0,
                    'multiple' => 0,
                    'ui' => 0,
                    'ajax' => 0,
                    'return_format' => 'value',
                    'placeholder' => '',
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'field_5f7efde2f2429',
                    'label' => 'Checkbox',
                    'name' => 'checkboxfield',
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'instructions' => '',
                    'required' => 0,
                    'conditional_logic' => array(
                        array(
                            array(
                                'field' => 'field_5f7efd35f2428',
                                'operator' => '==',
                                'value' => 'checkbox',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    'wrapper' => array(
                        'width' => '',
                        'class' => '',
                        'id' => '',
                    ),
                    'return_format' => 'array',
                    'default_value' => '<i class="fas fa-check font-size-60 white width-1em"></i>',
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'field_5f7f050f2d6e7',
                    'label' => 'Product',
                    'name' => 'pdp_product_one',
                    'type' => 'post_object',
                    'instructions' => '',
                    'required' => 0,
                    'conditional_logic' => array(
                        array(
                            array(
                                'field' => 'field_5f7efd35f2428',
                                'operator' => '==',
                                'value' => 'product',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    'wrapper' => array(
                'width' => '',
                'class' => '',
                'id' => '',
            ),
            'post_type' => array(
                0 => 'product',
                1 => 'product_variation',
            ),
            'taxonomy' => array(
            ),
             'taxonomy' => '',
            'allow_null' => 1,
            'multiple' => 0,
            'return_format' => 'object',
            'ui' => 1,
            ),        
            ), 
        ),
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: well - Your `echo $test` is outside the `while loop` so that probably won't echo anything until you put it in there